# How to write correctly a multiclass perceptron

Tags: python, perceptron, pattern-recognition

I am learning *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* and I was required to write a **multiclass perceptron** like this:

---

there are vectors: `v_i = [v_i0, v_i1, v_i2, ..., v_im], i = (1, 2, ..., n)`

write them to augmented style: `x_i = [v_i0, v_i1, v_i2, ..., v_im, 1]`

initial value `w_i(0) = [0 for _ in range(m)]`, `C`

```
for iteration ITER:
    for i in range(n):
    step = k = ITER * n + i
    use x_i as learning example:
    calculate d_j = w_j(k) * x_i, j = (1, 2, ..., n)
    if d_i(k) > d_j(k) is TRUE for any (j != i):
        w_j(k+1) = w_j(k)
    else if exists l such that d_i(k) <= d_l(k):
        w_i(k+1) = w_i(k) + C * x_i
        w_l(k+1) = w_l(k) - C * x_i
        w_j(k+1) = w_j(k) for any (j != i,l)
```

---

Then I have a question that:

if there are N vectors `w_l(k)` such that `d_i(k) <= d_l(k)`

should I do `w_i(k+1) = w_i(k) + C * x_i` once only when all comparations between `d_i` and `d_j` is over so that `w_i(k+1) = w_i(k) + C * x_i`

like this:

```py
        PUNISH = 0
        for _j in range(1,n):
            j = (i + _j) % n
            if d[i] > d[j]:
                COUNT += 1
            else:
                w[j] -= C * x[i]
                PUNISH += 1
        if PUNISH > 0:
            w[i] += C * x[i]
```

or I do `w_i(k+1) = w_i(k) + C * x_i` each time `d_i(k) <= d_l(k)` so that `w_i(k+1) = w_i(k) + N * C * x_i`

```py
        for _j in range(1,n):
            j = (i + _j) % n
            if d[i] > d[j]:
                COUNT += 1
            else:
                w[i] += C * x[i]
                w[j] -= C * x[i]
```